# Index match function VBA with 2 matches

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do is to convert the following simple formula:

```
INDEX(Data!$E:$E,MATCH(1,($A4=Data!$B:$B)*(J$3=Data!$D:$D),0))
```

Into VBA code:

```
Sub MyTest()
Dim destinationWs As Worksheet, dataWs As Worksheet
Dim destinationLastRow As Long, dataLastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim IndexRng As Range, MatchRng As Range, MatchSecond As Range

Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyTest")
Set dataWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

destinationLastRow = destinationWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
dataLastRow = dataWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Set IndexRng = dataWs.Range("E2:E" & dataLastRow)
Set MatchRng = dataWs.Range("B2:B" & dataLastRow)
Set MatchSecond = dataWs.Range("D2:D" & dataLastRow)

For x = 2 To destinationLastRow

On Error Resume Next
'=INDEX(Data!$E:$E,MATCH(1,($A4=Data!$B:$B)*(J$3=Data!
a = Application.Match(1, destinationWs.Range("A" & x).Value, MatchRng, destinationWs.Range("C1").Value, MatchSecond, 0)
MyValue = Application.Index(IndexRng, a)
destinationWs.Range("C" & x).Value = MyValue

$D:$D),0))
On Error GoTo 0

Next x

End Sub
```

When I run the query the result is "No".

Could someone point me towards the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Use `destinationWs.Evaluate` with your original formula as a string.

Comment: The best way to do this is to use variant arrays and loop.  Application.Match does not work as an array type formula in vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `($A4=Data!$B:$B)*(J$3=Data!$D:$D)` does not work in VBA without looping.

I recommend to use `Evaluate`:

```
RetVal = destinationWs.Evaluate("INDEX(Data!$E:$E,MATCH(1,($A" & x & "=Data!$B:$B)*(J$3=Data!$D:$D),0))")
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a column of about 103 items that will need to be filled with this formula and not really sure how .Evaluate would help in this case

Comment: @BigBen @Kurt as BigBen commented. See my edit. you can add a variable `x` from your loop as row number. You can do the same for `J$3` if needed like `J$" & x - 1 & "`